# How to write index query in postgresql

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql, indexing

in sql server index query written as follows
`SELECT *
FROM TabEmp
WITH (INDEX(idx_TabEmp))`

in same way how to write query in postgresql and how to use indexes in postgresql.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL comes with a very advanced planner, that does it's best to use all possible means in order to deliver query details in the most efficient way.

When it comes to the indexes, one has only to create them on the proper columns, most likely the ones used in the `FROM` (explicit notation), `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clauses. As [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-intro.html) says:

> Once an index is created, no further intervention is required: the
>   system will update the index when the table is modified, and it will
>   use the index in queries when it thinks doing so would be more
>   efficient than a sequential table scan.

Of course, you will have to [`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-analyze.html) your tables and look through the [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) output to understand what actually database is doing to process your query.

---

**EDIT**

My main everyday job is administration of a set of Billing production systems, running on ORACLE, so I know what hints are. As administrator I know my schemas and data very well, and in most cases I do know what is the best plan to execute my query.

Now, as ORACLE provide *lots* of different features, it's optimizer simply cannot “catch up” on the amount of possible paths. Therefore they went another way and added hints. And I do use them, 'cos there is no other way for me to force the specific plan that I know should perform best, no matter what I do with stats on the involved relations.

PostgreSQL went another way. Instead of providing hints, they were spending lots of hours in making the planner as good as it is today. I'm impressed, and *this is where PostgreSQL just kicks all other RDBMSes out* of the ring. IMHO.

Yes, not always you get the best plans with PostgreSQL. But there are ways to reach the goal. As other have already pointed out:

1. you should know your data and you should know what the best plan would look like;
2. use proper tools, like `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` together with http://explain.depesz.com/
3. make sure you have proper stats;
4. play with `enable_*` settings to really get the right plan;
5. if still no luck, look into the data and *understand* the reasons why chosen plan is not the best one. I assume that you will find a data distribution skew that don't match the way PostgreSQL gather stats for some particular attributes involved in your query;
6. adjust `SET STATISTICS` for the columns that you've found to have data skews;
7. if still no luck, you can use other techniques, like range or list partitioning, [partial indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22295/8017), CTEs, there're lots of.

In my experience with PostgreSQL it was *never* necessary to use hints. And despite the fact that adding a hint is “fast and easy”, I always prefer to solve the badly performing query via common means, as hint might do a bad job in case data distribution or database usage pattern changes (quite common scenario).

The only place where I see hints *might* be usable: hotfixing production issues of a closed source software you're using / supporting. But this also is not the case if you do a deep and thorough QA and Performance testing before rolling out new releases.

If you're still in need of a hints, take a look into [plantuner](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/plantuner) by Oleg Bartunov and Teodor Sigaev. This extension is not in the standard PostgreSQL distribution, but given Oleg and Teodor are in the core PostgreSQL Development team (they created GIN, GIST and FTS for the project), I would expect the code to be quite stable.

Comment: So does SQL Server but it still allows you to override the plan with index hints. Are you saying there is no syntax for this in Postgres on the grounds that the planner is perfect?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I think the assumption not that the planner is perfect but rather that not using a suitable index is considered a bug in the planner. Whether or not Postgres should support hints is a **very** heated debate. See here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Features_We_Do_Not_Want

Comment: @MartinSmith, some MHO and a link to the extension provided.